# Trying to find the lyapunov function

Tags: derivatives

I have the system that I want to show the global asymptotic stability of the origin

$$\dot{x_1} = x_2 \\
\dot{x_2} = -g(k_1 x_1 + k_2 x _2) $$ where k1 and k2 are positive numbers.

Also,
$$g(y)y > 0 $$ for all $y\neq 0$ and
$$\lim_{|y|\rightarrow \infty } \int_{0}^{y} g(\xi)d\xi = +\infty $$

With this information, I can see that I want to bring the derivative of my Lyapunov function to take form of

$$\dot{V}=-(k_1 x_1+k_2 x_2)g(k_1 x_1 + k_2 x_2) \\$$
so that I can say the derivative is  negative definite, and that my Lyapunov function should take the combination of integral and quadratic form to have radially unboundedness. 
I tried to back track from V_dot, just to realize it's not so feasible to get the original function from its partial derivatives. Second approach I tried is with

$$V = \int_{0}^{x_1}g(\xi)d\xi + 0.5x_2^2$$ 
but it seems that its derivatives wouldn't tell me much info either. What would be a good next step to do to the candidate function?